# Which function ($f$) is continuous nowhere but $|f(x)|$ is continuous everywhere?

Tags: calculus, continuity, examples-counterexamples, absolute-value

> Which function ($f$) is continuous nowhere but $|f(x)|$ is continuous everywhere?

I found this question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78980/i-m-stuck-at-this-calculus-problem-closed), the question seems much interesting but for obvious reason it is closed there, I was wondering how to derive such a function?

Comment: you should either put $|x|\to |f|$ or take any discontinuous $f$ as an answer

Comment: You might want to work this out for yourself, so here is a hint: take a non-zero constant function for $|f(x)|$ (which is what I think you must mean, with $f$ mapping real line to real line). Then you need to think of a way of constructing $f(x)$ so that it is discontinuous - how could you make it discontinuous at a point? How could you use that on enough points to make it discontinuous everywhere?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could take
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&x\in \mathbb Q \\
-1&x\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q\end{cases}$$

Comment: Could you explain how?

Comment: I assume you meant that $x\mapsto|f(x)|$ should be continuous everywhere. That is true here because $|f(x)|=1$ for all $x$. Did you mean something else by "$|x|$ is continuous everywhere"?

Comment: Also known as $f=2\cdot\chi_{\Bbb Q}-1,$ for those familiar with [characteristic/indicator functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).